# Разложить целое число на простые множители

Tags: python

Задача: составить программу, которая: разложит целое число на простые множители, выведет на экран все простые множители (в порядке возрастания) и их порядки

Я написал данную программу, но на некоторые числа она не работает. Например 7, 3. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
N = int(input("Введите число:"))
F=N
for i in range(2, F): 
   if N % i==0:
       d=0
       for B in range(2, i):
           if i % B ==0 :
               d+= 1
       if d == 0:
           por = 0 
           while N % i ==0:
               por += 1
               N=N//i
           print("делитель",i,"порядок",por)
```

Comment: а какие множители у числа 7 вы хотите получить?

Comment: кстати, настоятельно рекомендую использовать понятные имена для переменных, а не эти вот N, F, d. Послезавтра уже все забудется и будет непонятно какая переменная что означает.

Answer (score 3):

у вас не срабатывает при вводе простых чисел, потому что вы не проверяете ситуацию, когда не удалось найти множители

сделайте вот так - теперь будет рассматриваться и множитель `F`

```
for i in range(2, F+1):
```

P.S.

ну и вообще разложить на простые множители можно гораздо оптимальнее - у вас сложность O(n^2), ее можно снизить, если не перебирать одни и те же множители многократно и ограничиться числами до sqrt(n) (правда опять же надо аккуратно учесть возможность того что у вас число или простое или имеет простой множитель > sqrt(n) - такой множитель очевидно может быть только 1)